# Required Attendees are exported as GUIDs in Excel and Excel Online in Dynamics CRM 2015 Update 1

Tags: dynamics-crm

When I try to export my Appointments in Excel or in Excel Online, the Required Attendees column are exported in the form of GUIDs.

Is this by design?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is by design. Required Attendees is a field of type [Activity Party](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328549.aspx) which is exported as GUIDs.

Comment: Yes, but I had opened a case with Microsoft, I got a reply saying that this is found to be a 'bug' in the system and will probably be fixed in the upcoming release of Dynamics CRM Online.